# Strange behavier with generate JSON from object

Tags: java, json, jackson

This is part of my code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OAType", propOrder = {
    "cDefCamelTDPDataList",
})
public class OAType {

    @XmlElement(name = "c-def-camel-TDP-data-list", required = true)
    protected cDefCamelTDPDataListType cDefCamelTDPDataList;
    ...
```

When I create json with:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);

mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(tag); // Object tag
```

I get:

```
{
"cDefCamelTDPDataList" : { },
"cdefCamelTDPDataList" : { },
...
```

I didn't understand where is mistake, why does Jackson create 2 times cDefCamelTDPDataList field?

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled Jackson to use fields. But by default also getter/setter are enabled. I assume that you have an getter named `getCdefCamelTDPDataList()`.

If you only want to process fields you have to disable getter/setters first:

```
mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.ALL, Visibility.NONE); // disable getters/setters/is...
mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```